# Where to put headers in CodeIgniter 4 as API?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cors, preflight

I am sending cross origin requests to my API that I build with CodeIgniter 4.
The request comes from `axios.post()` using React.

As axios.post using content-type application/json, the request is not simple and it sends a preflight / options request.

Now I'm getting

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I added the following to my `app/Controllers/Basecontroller.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}

// ...
```

but this is not resolving my issue.

I'm now wondering what is the best place to put the headers?

In addition, why I ask, I have different Controllers for different purposes, where one should allow put and delete and another should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a filter that has the responsibility to handle CORS problems, in my case i use the filter gllobally, but you can use it only on the endpoints that you like ,it usually looks like this:

```
 *
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @param array|null       $arguments
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
{
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: --YOUR IP OR DOMAIN HERE--');
    if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: --YOUR IP OR DOMAIN HERE--");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content-type, timeout');
        --YOU CAN ADD OR REMOVE HEADERS BASED ON YOUR NEEDS--
        die();
    }
}

/**
 * Allows After filters to inspect and modify the response
 * object as needed. This method does not allow any way
 * to stop execution of other after filters, short of
 * throwing an Exception or Error.
 *
 * @param RequestInterface  $request
 * @param ResponseInterface $response
 * @param array|null        $arguments
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
{
    //
}
```

- For more information about CI4 filters please refer to : [CI4
  Filters](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html),
- For more information about CORS errors please refer to :    [CORS
  Errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)

Comment: I added your filter to my app and applied it to the `$globals` list to test it. It is calling the filter, but it is not resolving the preflight  issue.

Comment: is the CORS error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. , or has it changed?

Comment: Yes it's the same error

Comment: Btw: instead of putting my domain, I added *

Comment: Can you help me, why is that every time im using authorization header i get CORS error but when i don't add headers to my request it status is 200? i already update my .htaccess and headers codes. is there other file need to configure for my codeigbiter 4 project accept authorization header. thanks you.